# When the layer is loaded, some points from the graphics are missing

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

When I load one of my layers, some random parts of the graphics are missing. However, the data for the missing part is still accessible from the UI. Any suggestion why this might be happening?

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/z286U.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoCLy.jpg

Comment: I have a similar problem with circles where some are trimmed.
Might relate to the problem you're facing: https://imgur.com/a/i9huzWc